# Laravel Unittest of a model that contains another model

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I've made two Laravel models, `Module` & `ModuleDone`.

**Module.php**:

```
class Module extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'id', 'domain','level', 'description', 'sbu'
    ];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->domain . $this->level." ".$this->description." (".$this->sbu.")";
    }
}
```

**ModuleDone.php**:

```
class ModuleDone extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
      'date', 'date_start', 'date_end'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
      'id', 'date','modules_id','result','date_start','date_end'
    ];

    public function Module() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'modules_id');
    }


    public function getDescriptionHeaderAttribute(){
      if ($this->result != null) {
        return $this->Module->domain.$this->Module->level.' ('. $this->result.')';
      } else {
        return $this->Module->domain.$this->Module->level.' (S: '.
      $this->date_start->format('d-m-Y').')';
      }
    }
 }
```

This is a unit test code for the `Module` class:

```
public function testGetFullNameAttribute()
{
  $module = new Module([
    'domain' => 'T',
    'level' => '9',
    'description' => 'Test',
    'sbu' => '10',
  ]);

  $this->assertEquals($module->fullName, 'T9 Test (10)', "FullNameAttribe");
}
```

My question is, what would a unit test for `getDescriptionHeaderAttribute()` look like without saving anything to the database, or without seeding anything in the database?

Comment: is it a strict requirement to not write to the database? If you for example use the trait `DatabaseTransactions` you can use the database normally but changes are not persisted across tests. The suggested methodology in the laravel docs is to use factories to generate models that do go in the database and then use the testing traits to somehow reset the database

Comment: Not writing is not a strict requirement, but I'd like to prevent using lots of Test-seeding, and also test database-records messing up the tests that do require database-records from the TestSeed.
Would you recommend to create persisted Objects in each test?

Comment: `DatabaseTransactions` will wrap each test case in a transaction and then roll it back when the test is done so there's no changes persisted across tests but the database is not reset either.

Comment: Nice! I'll look into that! Thanks

Comment: $module = new Module(); will not save anything unless you call ->save(); function on it. So you are already writing nothing to db.

Module::create(); automatically saves the instance to db.